# Autowiring services in Vaadin view and components not working

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, vaadin

Hello fellow programmers! I am relatively new to Vaadin so spare me please. 
I am trying to autowire my service layer into my view as follows:

```
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "First time bruh", shortName = "Project Base")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private TextField filterText = new TextField();
    private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>(Customer.class);
    private CustomerForm customerForm = new CustomerForm(this);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
```

and the customerService dependency injections works properly, however when i try to use it in a component it returns null:

```
@Route
public class CustomerForm extends FormLayout {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
```

I've tried annotating the class with @Component and @SpringComponent but the dependency injection does not work and i think that the problem does not come from the fact that the class is not a bean, because MainView Class is also not a bean.

My wish is the custom sub components that i create to have access to the service layer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you create the customerForm yourself using `new CustomerForm()`, or is it an actual Route? If it's the former, injection doesn't work that way. If it's the latter, are you trying to access the injected service in the constructor? Because field-injected properties are injected *after* the constructor has finished - you should in that case use constructor injection (add the service as parameter of the constructor, and remove autowired annotation on the field)

Comment: @KasparScherrer i removed the Route annotation and tried what you suggested:
`public CustomerForm(MainView mainView, CustomerService customerService) {
  this.mainView = mainView;
  this.customerService = customerService;`
But it is still null.

Comment: @AlexVulchev, you might benefit from this article (or video) that explains Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control with Spring and Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/blog/community-answer-understanding-inversion-of-control-and-dependency-injection Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vaadin UI, you can inject only in route endpoints (views that have the `@Route` annotation), and only if that view is opened by navigating to the route specified in the annotation. (Because only then then instantiation of that view is done "automatically").

As a rule of thumb: Whenever you instantiate something yourself using the `new` keyword, injection/autowiring does not work.

What I understand of your situation is:
You have a `MainView`, within that you want to add a `CustomerForm`.

Here is how to achieve that:
Inject the `CustomerService` into the `MainView`, and pass the `CustomerService` instance into the constructor of `CustomerForm`

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView(CustomerService customerService) { // customerService will be injected
        CustomerForm customerForm = new CustomerForm(customerService);
        add(customerForm);
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomerForm extends FormLayout {
    public CustomerForm (CustomerService customerService){
        ...
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to make the `CustomerForm` a`@Component` (do remember to scan it properly in the spring configuration class), inject the service into it, and then inject the whole form into the `MainView`:

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView(CustomerForm customerForm) {  // customerForm will be injected
        add(customerForm);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class CustomerForm extends FormLayout {
    public CustomerForm (CustomerService customerService){ // customerService will be injected
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Injection doesn't work when you create the instances yourself, using the `new` keyword.

If the class is annotated with `@Route`, dependencies will be injected by the Vaadin framework when navigating to that route.

In your case, if you're not navigating to it, you will have to make it a Spring bean. Add `@Component` or `@SpringComponent` (alias for the first), and either autowire it in your `MainView`, or autowire the `ApplicationContext` and get it from there.

It's fine to have both `@Route` and `@Component`, so that it can be autowired, but also navigated to.

Remember to choose an appropriate scope if you add the `@Component` annotation, either `@UIScope` to reuse the same instance while navigating around, or `Scope.PROTOTYPE` to always create a new one.

Comment: This is the better answer than the accepted one.